# Seagate HDD stuck at "Detecting IDE devices"

Tags: hard-drive

I probably already suspect the answer, but anyway's here goes.

Recently my PC just randomly crashed and upon restart, would not barely get past POST screen and get stuck on "Detecting IDE Drives...". I isolated the problem to my Seagate main drive. I went into diskpart and tried list disk, but the drive would not even display there. Does this mean my drive is pretty much dead?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated while I reinstall Windows.

Comment: It sounds like a dying hard drive. If you take the hard drive out (or just disconnect it) does the computer POST at normal speeds?

Comment: Potentially yes, there are steps to possibly recover the data if you are interested.  Before you give up though, does the drive show up in you BIOS?  What happens if you attach the drive to a different computer?

Answer (score 2):

If the system doesn't say HDD FAILURE or words to that respect, and the HDD is spinning ok and not making a noise, the controller board on the bottom may of malfunctioned - Track down an identical drive with the same model number and try the board from that - This worked for me once and truly saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your IDE cable. If it not does not work then your HDD is dying.